# intransitive usage of the verb "involve"

Tags: grammar

> Pretending to be someone else, with all the gestures, actions, and language that **involves**, gives children practice thinking divergently as they consider different things they can pretend to do.

It's rare that I come across this intransitive uage of the verb 'involve'.

Does this look grammatical?

Comment: Having an optional "involved" (*Pretending to be someone else, with all the gestures, actions, and language [involved]...* would probably be the most common way to put it.

Comment: I think that  ... actions, and language that **that / it** involves ..." is probably what a native BrE speaker would use.

Answer (score 1):

This usage is grammatical because it's not an intransitive use, but actually a [reduced relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause).  You could reword the relevant language as: "...with all the gestures, actions, and language ***which*** that involves...."  In this case, the word "which" supplies the required object for "involve" that otherwise could be omitted to form a reduced relative clause.

Comment: I believe another option also could be "that it (=pretending) involves"

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko In my reading,  a stressed "that" in the original sentence has to be the subject of "involves."  If "it" were the subject, it could not be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an intransitive use of "involve." It is just a carelessly written sentence. It is bad style rather than bad grammar.

I believe I talked to you the other day about ellipsis and its frequency with respect to fronting of relative clauses.

This is a perfect example. The sentence means

> Pretending to be someone else, with all the gestures, actions, and language which that involves, gives children

or even more explicitly

> Pretending to be someone else, which [pretence] involves many gestures, actions, and language, gives children

Such ellipsis at the beginning of relative clauses is common especially in speech, where complex sentence structures are rare.

In writing, especially complex sentences with several clauses and phrases, it can make parsing a sentence difficult. Except in very simple cases, my style is to avoid it.